# Unmarshalling from SOAP xml, getSOAPBody() method returns Null

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, pojo

While unmarshalling a Soap response getSOAPBody returns null. 
 I have tried using XMLStreamReader which works in this case. But I want to know a way to do it via ByteArrayInputStream.
 What would be the correct fix for it. I am attaching below POJOmand package-info.java file.

Also if I make "xsi:type="xsd:string" to "xsi:type="string" it seems to work. How should I mofify my bean class such that it works?

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(

        namespace = "http://tempuri.org/",

        xmlns = {

                @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "soap", namespaceURI = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),

                @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xsi", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/"),

                @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xsd", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")

        })
package org.tempuri;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**TestJAX.java**

```
    package org.test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

import org.tempuri.WIResponse;

/**
 * Test Class
 * 
 * @author vijay.prakash
 *
 */
public class TestJAX {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, JAXBException, IOException, SOAPException {
        // xmlReadingWay
        /*
         * XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory(); XMLStreamReader xsr =
         * xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("D:\\BACKUPWARS\\some.xml"));
         * 
         * xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to Envelope tag xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to Body
         * tag xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to getNumberResponconse tag
         */

        // byteway
        String object = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n"
                + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\r\n"
                + " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n"
                + "    <soap:Body>\r\n" + "        <WIResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\r\n"
                + "            <WIResult xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">20702458ghhc</WIResult>\r\n"
                + "        </WIResponse>\r\n" + "    </soap:Body>\r\n" + "</soap:Envelope>";

        String str = new String(object.getBytes(), "utf-8");
        final MessageFactory messFac = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = messFac.createMessage(null, new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));

        message.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "utf-8");
        System.out.println("message: " + message.getSOAPBody());

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(WIResponse.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        System.out.println("message.getSOAPBody(): " + message.getSOAPBody());
        Object je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());

        WIResponse wi = (WIResponse) je;

        /*
         * //JAXBElement<WIResponse> je =
         * unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument(),
         * WIResponse.class);
         */
        System.out.println(wi.getWIResult());

    }
}
```

**soap xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <WIResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <WIResult xsi:type="xsd:string">20702458ghhc</WIResult>
        </WIResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**WIResponse.java**

```
    package org.tempuri;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "WIResponse", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
public class WIResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "WIResult", required = true, type = java.lang.String.class)
    String wIResult;

    public String getWIResult() {
        return wIResult;
    }

    public void setWIResult(String wIResult) {
        this.wIResult = wIResult;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be some sort of parsing bug (getSOAPBody() doesn't seem to properly handle namespace resolution).

The 'easiest' way to solve this is to retrieve the raw XML from the SOAP message yourself, however in typical Java fashion, the solution is convoluted and bureaucratic.

You may have to modify the example code below:

```
//https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPPart.html
javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart GSP = SomeSOAPMessage.getSOAPPart();

//https://static.javadoc.io/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl/1.4.0/com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/util/JAXMStreamSource.html
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JAXMStreamSource GC = GSP.getContent();

//https://static.javadoc.io/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl/1.4.0/com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/util/ByteInputStream.html
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.ByteInputStream BIS = GC.getInputStream();

byte[] ByteArray = BIS.getBytes();

java.lang.String Data = new java.lang.String(ByteArray, "UTF-8");
```

Basically, SOAPPart from the message, get the content of that SOAPPart which is a JAXMStreamSource.

Then from the JAXMStreamSource, it can either have a 'Reader' or a 'InputStream' (in my case, I found it has an 'InputStream'). The InputStream is likely dictated by the application type (in my case, xop+xml, which is 'binary' XML), however in testing I found it was of type ByteInputStream, which is an extended class of ByteArrayInputStream.

Finally, you can convert the ByteArray to a string. This string will contain the entire XML (including XML version header), which you can then parse using whatever preferred XML handler class you'd like to use.

(Full name resolution and commented references included to assist with understanding how this works.)

Comment: > doesn't seem to properly handle namespace resolution. 

This part saved my day. Have to integrate with an old SOAP interface with non-existent WSDL and very similar XML as OP has. The difference between getting nulls back vs real values was changing @XmlElement(name = "uuid") to @XmlElement(name = "uuid", namespace = "proper-namespace-path") for every single field. Class-level annotation didn't seem to do the trick.